# How to enable Overscroll effect in android ionic 6 react

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic6, ionic-react

Sorry for my title; I’m not really familiar with the effect in question. But here the simple thing is how to make my Ionic 6 react page have an effect like this picture.

[Like android native](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJJDO.gif)

I’ve tried several ways to modify the style and CSS, but it hasn’t worked either.
Thank you for your help.
regards

I've tried using css, but the result is nil, I hope to find a simple way to make this effect happen on the ionic 6 react

Answer (score 0):

Right now it is not possible, due to this animation is bound to the capabilities of the chromium webview which does not support it, yet. It was already discussed on several places like the github page of ionic here:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/25059

Ultimately, the chromium developers need to implement this. There is already a ticket for that:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1256902&q=overscroll%20stretch&can=2